# Notepad++ and Perl, End STDIN. Ctrl+Z in the console not working

Tags: perl, notepad++

** Title original said Ctrl+D

I have perl set up to execute and run in Notepad++.

Here's the Execute command:

```
NPP_SAVE
cd "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)"
C:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl "$(FILE_NAME)"
```

I'm trying to work through an example that reads in a list via STDIN, but I can't end the input, because CTRL+Z doesn't appear to work in Notepad++'s console.  I press it and nothing happens,  it doesn't continue the program, or end.  I eventually have to terminate.

Here's the code I'm running

```
#!perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my @list_of_strings = <STDIN>;

@list_of_strings = reverse @list_of_strings;

print @list_of_strings;
```

Comment: In Windows cmd shell end of file Ctrl-D is Ctrl-Z, so try that.

Comment: Thanks, tried Ctrl-Z, that performs the undo action in Notepad++'s console.  It doesn't  terminate the user input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://sourceforge.net/p/notepad-plus/discussion/482781/thread/db271da3/:

> While your program is executing press F6 (again), in string "Exit message" type EOF's ASCII code < alt>+<26> and press "Send" button.

I'm not completely sure what that means, and don't have windows to try it, but that's the first hit from a google search on "notepad++ console end of file".

Comment: This looks like what I'm after.  I might be a little dim though, sending literally the text "<alt>+<26>" only sends that string, not an EOF.  I'll see if I can follow up on that thread.  Thanks

Comment: try holding down the alt key and pressing the 2 and 6 keys

Comment: Tried that.  It gives me "→".  Which I tried sending, and it does nothing

Answer (score 1):

In Windows cmd shell I use Ctrl-Z for end of file, while reading from STDIN, so it sounds likely that that would work for you too. Assuming of course that you have some prompt to type into when executing through Notepad++.

Otherwise, you could use the diamond operator instead, which would allow you to insert debug input through a file instead. The diamond operator uses *both*  STDIN and file content, depending on whether `@ARGV` is empty or not, and the functionality is identical, which is ideal for debugging purposes.

Your script could just be

```
print reverse <>;
```

Which will allow you to apply it to files as well as STDIN. I.e.:

```
C:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl "$(FILE_NAME)" "$(INPUT_FILE)"
```

Or you could patch your program to add your test input file directly:

```
@ARGV = "input.txt";
```

This will work exactly as if you gave the file name as argument to the program.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.
Ctrl+Z does work in the cmd, but in Notepad++ that appears to perform the "undo" action.  So entering CTRL+Z, <enter> only removes the last line I typed.

The script above works fine in cmd, but I'd like to get it working in Notepad++ with STDIN

Comment: @topher-j And if you use the diamond operator instead? Combined with an input file?

Comment: It does work if I use a file.  But I want to get STDIN working.

Comment: @topher-j If you use the diamond operator it will work exactly the same way with STDIN as with files. That is why I suggested that workaround. Perl will automatically use either `<ARGV>` or `<STDIN>` to read input, depending on whether `@ARGV` is empty or not.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion, but I want the ability to type the input into the console, and interact with the program while it's running.

Comment: I see. Your current program cannot be interacted with, though.

Comment: By the way, are you sure that you can read from stdin at all this way? You could do a workaround, such as reading each line of input and exiting on a regex match criteria, such as `/^quit/` or `/^$/`.